# Best way to redirect non-www to www?

Tags: url, redirect, dns, http-status-code-301, no-www

What would be the best way to redirect my non-www urls to www url in my site.

I think they are being redirected with a 301 redirect now but traffic that is being sent to my non-www is not tracked properly with google analytics. 
So I guess it's not configured properly.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on which web server do you use. Anyway, I think the answer already exists here.

Comment: I assumed he uses apache...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-www to www can be done using Apache Rewrite Engine and htaccess file.
Create a .htaccess file in your public html directory with following content..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.youraddress.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.youraddress.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```