# converting short domain to full domain URL

Tags: linux, .htaccess, dns

I am looking for a script to convert short domain link to main domain URL such as the below example? It's like Facebook.com/username , it will automatically redirect you to the complete URL www.facebook.com/username

```
When user type short domain = http://abc.com/leon

the system should automatically CONVERT IT TO main domain URL = http://www.abc.com/leon
```

Do i need to edit any on the .htaccess? If so, what is the script should i add?

I have tried the following script on .htaccess , but it doesn't convert to main URL

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ /Test.php?pname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please help.

Cheers

Comment: I have tried the following script on .htaccess but it doesn't work to convert =>  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ /Test.php?pname=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: You aren't writing a webserver, you're configuring someone else's.  So the webmasters stack exchange might be a better place to talk about this.  It's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Alright... Identified this may be under the category of DNS issue and found this link => [Best way to redirect non-www to www?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033302/best-way-to-redirect-non-www-to-www)  ; as well the following script seem work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.youraddress.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.youraddress.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```